Laptop cannot wake from sleep, bluetooth erro
When I close and then open my laptop, I can see the login screen for Ubuntu, however the screen goes black and gives me the following error:
[5763.700208] Bluetooth: hc10: command 0x0c01 tx timeout
[5763.700272] Bluetooth: hc10: Opcode 0x0c01 failed -110
[5765.825190] Bluetooth: hc10: command 0x0c01 tx timeout
[5765.828193] Bluetooth: hc10: Opcode 0x0c1a failed -110
[5766.251739] Bluetooth: hc10: Opcode 0x0c1a failed -16

I have a background in technical support, but really only in Windows and Mac OS X. I wanted to learn some Linux basics for fun, but I am honestly completely perplexed.
I tried disabling Bluetooth in settings and that does seem to allow the computer to wake from sleep.
I am using an Nvidia GPU on this machine, but I doubt it's related. I also don't use that GPU for anything intensive in Ubuntu, only in Windows.
If I am missing some piece of information that will be helpful please let me know.
